# oracle select if not exists insert

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert

Suppose I have a table A with two columns b and c. I want to fetch a specific value, and if it doesn't exist, initialize it with zero. something like:

```
if  exists (select c from A where b=1) 
{return  (select c from A where b=1)}
else
{ (insert into A values(1,0)) return 0}
```

is it possible to do it all in one statement?

Comment: A single SQL statement *either* returns rows *or* modifies the data.  It doesn't generally do both.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I don't think the OP is looking to insert into the table; he is still only interested in the return value, of 0 in the ELSE branch of the IF statement.

Comment: Well, obviously the OP did want the INSERT too (see his Comment under my Answer).

Answer (score 1):

So, you want a statement (or a fragment to use in a bigger statement), that will return the value of c where b = 1, or return 0 if there are no rows with b = 1. Is that it?

What do you want to return if there are several rows where b = 1? Your question doesn't make much sense, if that's possible in your data. So, for the answer below, I assume that there may be **no duplicates in column b**. (Or, to be precise, it is not necessary that column b have no duplicates; but it **is** necessary that the value 1 appear no more than once in that column.)

```
select nvl( (select c from A where b = 1), 0 ) from dual;
```

will return a single value: if there is a row in table A where b = 1, it will return the corresponding c. If there are no rows with b = 1, the "scalar subquery" (the inner SELECT) will return NULL. NVL returns its second argument, if the first argument is NULL (otherwise it returns the first argument).

Now, strictly speaking, this solution is not 100% correct. If there is a row in table A, with b = 1 and c is NULL, then perhaps you want to return NULL, not 0. You will need to clarify if c can be NULL, and if it can, how you would want that handled. (If you want to return 0 in that case too, THEN the solution above is 100% correct.)

Comment: Your solution misses the insert part because I want to insert the data if it doesn't exist. about your question, I'm sure that several rows with b=1 are not possible. also, c will never be NULL.

Comment: @ayyoobimani - OK, so then Gordon Linoff's guess was right, you actually do want to do two things at the same time: SELECT (something) in both cases, and in case b = 1 does not exist in the table, you want to INSERT into the table? This will require two steps; you can do the INSERT first (but only if b = 1 is not already present in the table) and then you can do the SELECT - no conditional needed anymore, because you already know a row with b = 1 will be present (unless another session deletes it as soon as you put it in.)

Comment: Just to add - make sure that "b" is a primary/unique key in that table, otherwise the concept of "insert if not exists" generally fails in realistic environments (ie, more than one user)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the opposite, instead of checking if true, you can check if not exist and insert

```
INSERT INTO A (F1, F2)
SELECT F1, F2 FROM C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM A WHERE A.F1 = C.F1)
```

This will insert in A the values from B if they don't exist in A